# GDK Listener forced for numeric input only?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am developing glassware to receive a numeric value that will be queried in a database. Is there any way to utilize the Listener so that it only receives numeric input?

For example, if I say "1 2 3".. I want to avoid the possibility of glass hearing "1 to 3"

Thoughts?

Comment: No thoughts -- that's not how this works. If you show us your code we'll happily try to help you with specific implementation details. Show us what you've tried, and we'll help you get it right. So, explain, in detail, which listener you're talking about, its library and fully qualified classname will do, then show us how you're wiring it up to get data at all, then show us how you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about voice command listener. U can't make any change in voice interpretation logic until you are the developer of Google voice app.

So i think other alternatives may be :

1) Show digits 0-9 as menu options and let user select one. repeat the process until user entered whole number.

2) Allow user to inter number through mobile app, connected to glass via bluetooth/TCP/WWW. Just like MyGlass app.